# I have this seemingly simple volume of a solid of revolution, but the limits and function are unknown.

Tags: calculus, rotations, volume

[image: The problem and diagram]

How can I possibly find the numerical area of the region without knowing the function itself or the limits?

Comment: Hint: [Pappus's centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)

Comment: Oops, I saw your comment after I finished posting.  I had the same thought, although I don't know whether OP's course has discussed those (very useful) theorems (one for surface area, the second for volume).

Answer (score 1):

Using cylindrical coordinate system 
$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_a^b\int_{0}^{f(r)}rdzdrd \theta=2\pi \int_{a}^{b}f(r)rdr$$

We know the result is $2\pi$, therefore $$\int_{a}^{b}f(r)rdr=1$$

If the volume is made by revolving about $x=-1$, you can do similar thing but just shift the coordinate by -1. $$\int_{a+1}^{b+1}f(r+1)rdr=4$$

By substituting, you get $$\int_{a}^{b}f(r)rdr-\int_{a}^{b}f(r)dr=4$$

Thus we get the area $$\int_{a}^{b}f(r)dr=-3$$  Interesting enough, it seems that the graph in the book tries to make you think the area is positive.

Comment: For rotation around $x = -1$, the equation should be $2\pi\int_{a+1}^{b+1}f(r\color{red}{-}1)rdr=8\pi$.

Comment: Check your statements against the problem description again: the volume in the first case is $ \ 4 \pi \ $ , so your first integral should equal $ \ 2 \ $  . (And the area _should_ be positive: for a solid of revolution, this serves as an area _between_ curves, so its location "above or below"  the coordinate axes is irrelevant.) Your next-to-last integral equation, involving a difference, doesn't seem to jibe with what precedes it (I believe you'll find that difference should equal $ \ 2 \ $ ) .

Answer (score 1):

Pappus' (second) centroid theorem is of help here.  (I don't recognize the book you are taking this problem from, so I don't know if you've covered this topic.)  The volume of a solid of revolution is given by  $ V \ = \ 2 \pi \ r_c \ A \ $ , where $ \ r_c \ $ is the perpendicular distance of the centroid of the region being revolved from the axis of revolution.

Let the coordinates of the centroid be $ \ (\overline{x} \ , \ \overline{y} ) \ $ .  The volume of the solid produced by revolution about the $ \ y-$ axis is then

$$ V_y \ = \ 2 \pi \ \overline{x} \ A \ \ = \ \ 4 \pi \ \ , $$

while the volume of the solid produced by revolution about the vertical axis $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ $ , which is one unit further to the left, is

$$ V_{vert} \ = \ 2 \pi \ ( \overline{x} \ + \ 1) \ A \ \ = \ \ 8 \pi \ \ . $$

We can thus locate the $ \ x-$ coordinate of the centroid of the region $ \ S \ $ as $ \ \overline{x} \ = \ 1 \ $ , which thereby tells us that the area of said region is $ \ A \ = \ 2 \ $ .